# Best approach to reading and writing values from DLL at runtime

Tags: c#, xml, dll, configuration, class-library

I’m creating a class library DLL which will be used by others. I have no knowledge of what that project will be, what the project name will be and etc. When it’s all said and done, all I will be doing is handing them the DLL for any project to reference.

The problem now is that I need a way for my DLL to be able to read and load key/values from the project at runtime. The project will pass the key/values to my DLL and said DLL will do the reading and writing of these key/values. I’ve found out that there are multiple ways to do that:

1) User settings from Settings/Appconfig

2) Create a new XML file to read and write from

However both ways are not automated. Correct me if I’m wrong:

For 1) The project side will have to manually create a Settings file with the key/values my DLL needs.

For 2) The project side will have to manually create an XML file with the key/values my DLL needs. Plus my DLL will need to know where that XML is being saved by the project referencing it (so that I can read and write from it from the DLL)

This is where I need help. Is there a way I can achieve reading and writing values from my DLL at  runtime without the project having to do any manual work? And if not, what would be the best approach to go about this? Hand over a Settings file to the people who will be referencing my DLL?

Thanks!

Comment: What about a method in your dll to get/set the values?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the client (the project using your dll) will have to do *something* in order to use you dll, right. 
Your choice is to either define a way of configuration or to change your interface, so that the caller can provide the key-value pairs directly. You can still use app-settings from the consuming application's configuration-file. Your DLL can access them by using `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`without having to know anything about where the application is running. 
The only thing the other project would have to do is to provide the settings you need in the config.
But maybe you could elaborate a little more on what you are actually trying to do, "reading values" is not very specific.

Comment: Hi Mr Berger. Each client will have its own "local settings file" with key/values like "name", "id' and etc that is stored in a DB on the web and a copy is loaded onto a file in the project. For example, if the user changes their "name" from the project exe, my dll will upload it to the DB and update the local settings file. At the same time, my DLL will need to be able to read from this local settings file for certain checks like, is the new name same as the old name before uploading it to the DB?

Comment: Well okay. In that case, your DLL could easily be the maintainer of the configuration-file as well. So your interface would expose methods to change the data (i.e. `YourClass.SetUserName(string)`). When called, your methods apply validation, sync local config-file and database.
To get the current configuration, the calling application would query your component (i.e. `YourClass.GetCurrentConfig()`)

Comment: Do you mean having a separate config file for my DLL? I've tried setting my dll.config to 'copy always' but it doesn't seem to be appearing in my output folder. Or did you mean, passing a reference of the project's Settings file to my dll?

Comment: I think in your case using the configuration-file is not a good idea, since you want to change the settings at runtime. So why not have a json/xml file of your own, which only your dll knows and cares about.